# Understanding Bidual Space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am reading a book introducing bidual spaces of a normed space. It says for any normed space $\mathscr{X}$, if we define its bidual space as $\mathscr{X}^{**}$, then $\mathscr{X}\subset\mathscr{X}^{**}$, which can be seen as an expansion of the original space. I was wondering if we continue consider the bidual space of $\mathscr{X}^{**}$, will the expansion continue or stop within finite steps?

I find it was not true for all infinite dimensional space, now I want to know in which condition it will be true, for example, what if the space is compact or with other topological structures?

Comment: This statement is not true for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: @Abezhiko The question is clearly not about the *algebraic* bidual. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexive_space

Comment: @Hydre05236 your edit "what if the space is compact" is awkward. Only the zero space is compact.